# List Comprehension to append string to list each list item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm currently trying to learn the Twitter API and I'm working on a method that will prepare a string that's separated by a `|` for a threaded post and append the number of tweets to each element of the list.  So as an example:

```
tweet_thread = "this is going|to be a multipart|tweet thread about python"
tweets = (tweet_thread.split('|'))
tweet_list = []
count = 1
total = len(tweets)
if total > 1:
    for item in tweets:
        tweet_count = " " + str(count) + "/" + str(total)
        tweet_list.append(item + tweet_count)
        count +=1
```

This returns what I want:

```
['this is going 1/3', 'to be a multipart 2/3', 'tweet thread about python 3/3']
```

But I'm thinking there has to be a much more elegant/pythonic way of doing this, perhaps with a comprehension?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) is your friend.

Comment: f-strings may help with aesthetics...

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of enumerate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `f-string` and `list comprehension with enumerate`:

```
tweet_thread = tweet_thread.split('|')
result = [f"{i} {index}/{len(tweet_thread)}" for index,i in enumerate(tweet_thread,1)]  # not hardcoding length here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **enumerate** :

```
[elem+' '+str(i+1)+'/3' for i, elem in enumerate(tweet_thread.split('|'))]
```